# Dropdown in parent to pass selected value to child component and call different http requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need help with making http requests to methods in service based on dropdown search type with Rxjs Observables when i change the dropdown in angular and I am passing the dropdown value to the child component. Thank You in advance.

```js
child-component.ts

@Input() Type;
private data: any;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService){
switch(this.Type){
  case 't1': this.apiService.getAllByT1(this.Type).subscribe(result =>   {
    this.data = result;
  });
  break;
  case 't2': this.apiService.getAllByT2(this.Type).subscribe(result =>   {
    this.data = result;
  });
  break;
  case 't3': this.apiService.getAllByT3(this.Type).subscribe(result =>   {
    this.data = result;
  })
}

ngOnInit(){
}
```

```html
parent-component.html

<select [(ngModel)]="Type" class="form-control" (change)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
<option id="1" value="t1">t1</option>
<option id="2" value="t2">t2</option>
<option id="3" value="t3">t3</option>
</select>

<app-child [Type]="Type" (getAPI)="onOptionsSelected($event)"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code processing `@Input() Type` should not be in the `constructor` because none of the data bindings have been setup by angular yet. To process any `@Input()` variables you must do that in `ngOnInit()` or `ngOnChanges()`.

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) for `ngOnInit()` it states it is "A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has initialized all data-bound properties of a directive".

You should instead use the `ngOnChanges()` ([documentation link](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)) lifecycle hook because it "is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes" which is exactly what you're looking for.

Move your code from the `constructor` into `ngOnChanges()`.

```
child-component.ts

@Input() type;
private data: any;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService){
}

ngOnInit(){
}

ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.type) {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 't1': 
            this.apiService.getAllByT1(this.type).subscribe(result => {
                this.data = result;
            });
            break;
            case 't2': 
            this.apiService.getAllByT2(this.type).subscribe(result => {
                this.data = result;
            });
            break;
            case 't3': 
            this.apiService.getAllByT3(this.type).subscribe(result => {
                this.data = result;
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```